Random sample and its underlying sample space
A random sample of size $n$ is a random vector $X=(X_1, ..., X_n)$, where all $X_i$ are i.i.d., and are measurable functions on some sample space $\Omega$.
Let's say, $\Omega = \{H,T\}$, i.e., heads and tails. There exist just 4 functions from $\{H,T\}$ to $\{0,1\}$, so there is no way we can have an arbitrarily large number of i.i.d. random variables on $\Omega$. Does this mean that the sample space here is a cartesian product of $\Omega$ taken $n$ times, with each $X_i$ acting on its respective copy?
Then, for a given random sample, we can compute its empirical distribution
$$F_N^{*}(x) = P^{*}_n((-\infty, x])=\frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}I\{X_i \leq x\}$$
This distribution is something we measure, i.e., a measurable function, i.e., a random variable. From what space? Is it $\Omega$ or $\Omega \times \Omega \times ...  \times \Omega$?
